# application context

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

Пытаюсь развернуть вэб приложение на хостинге(там стоит томкат). По умолчанию tomcat предоставляет контекст к приложению равный имени war'ника, который я собираю мейвеном. Т.е. чтобы открыть моё приложение в строке адреса пишем, что-то вроде `сайт.com/имяWAR` , а нужно `сайт.com` ,т.е. как переопределить контекст с `имяWAR` на `/`? Это нужно сделать в коде приложения, т.к. доступа к томкату на хостинге у меня нет  и выставить там для своего war'ника contex path в `/` я не могу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А разве томкет автоматически не должен деплоить ваше приложение и показывать его по адресу без всяких /*war? Вам в любом случае нужно посмотреть настройки томкета на машине

Comment: автоматически томкат деплоит приложение по адресу 'localhost:8080/имяWAR'(видно в таблице на фото, стрелка 1), этот путь можно изменить стандартными средствами томкат(смотрите на фото, стрелка 2) выставив Contex Path(required) '/'. Но на хостинге такой возможности нет и к тому же, если я размещу два приложения, томкат не разрешает устанавливать обоим путь '/'. Необходимо путь к приложению установить, например в pom.xml, т.е. в коде приложения.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько помню, нужно использовать специальное имя `ROOT` для вашего WAR-файла, т.е. он должен называться `ROOT.war`

Comment: В pom.xml сделал так                                                                     `<build>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            ....
        </plugins>
    </build>` теперь при переходе по localhost:8080 открывается не стартовая страница томкат а моё приложение, на хостинге ещё не попробовал.

Comment: попробовал проделать тоже самое на хостинге - не работает, сайт открывается только при добавлении в путь `/ROOT`. Сайт `nice.biz.ua`, war архив залил под именем `nc`. Если перейти по ссылке `nice.biz.ua` - то ничего не работает, если так `nice.biz.ua/nc` - тогда всё норм.

Comment: А почему вы файл залили "под именем nc"?

Comment: А как? По умолчанию мавен собирает по артефактID и версии, выглядит так `nice-1.0`, для простоты переименовал в `nc`

Comment: Добавил в pom.xml такой плагин `<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>

                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>` и всё вроде бы заработало, но начала сбрасываться сессия, т.е. я авторизуюсь перехожу на другую страницу и авторизация слетает и с ней все переданные сервлетом в модель атрибуты. ??